Spring security при запуске сайта все равно используется базовая конфигурация, хотя есть пользовательская
Код взят с гайда по spring security. Страницы "/", "/home", "/login" существуют и описаны в контроллере. По идее, страницы "/", "/home" должны быть доступны без авторизации, но они все равно защищены. Добавляла @Order(1) к моей конфигурации, но это не помогло, также пыталась отключать csrf. Все равно при запуске сайта высвечивается лог: INFO 22436 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with
Файл CustomSecurityConfig:
package org.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
}

Файл MvcConfig:
package org.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}


@talex moved to Codidact меня все равно с localhost:8080/home перенаправляют на localhost:8080/login

Нужно разрешить анонимный доступ
.requestMatchers("/", "/home").anonymous()

